# Can't bind nested form group to form array in reactive Forms?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-eg-s1v5zs?file=src/app/app.component.html

> Could not  bind {form control} to data [
>     {
>       "group1": "",
>       "group2": {
>         "data": ""
>       }
>     }
>   ]
>
> > Need to bind using form control name

```
 <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <div formArrayName="features">
        <div class="row no-gutters form-group" *ngFor="let feature of features.controls; let i = index; let last = last"
            [formGroupName]="i">
            Grp:1 <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control px-2 col"
        formControlName="group1"
        title="feature"
        >
            <!-- //How to bind  value of data in html??? -->
            <div [formGroup]="group2">
                <input type="text"
                class="form-control px-2 col"
                formControlName="group2"
                title="feature"
                >
            </div>
            <button class="col btn btn-success" (click)="addFeature()">
                +
                </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <pre>
    {{ features.value|json}}
  </pre>
</form>

typeScript
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.addFeature();
  }
  formGroup = this.fb.group({
    features: this.fb.array([])
  });
  get features(): FormArray {
    return this.formGroup.get("features") as FormArray;
  }
  addFeature(): void {
    let data = this.fb.group({
      group1: new FormControl("grp_1"),
      group2: this.fb.group({
        data: new FormControl("grp_2")
      })
    });
    this.features.push(data);
  }`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create nested form with array of object then you should use FormGrop.

**Try this:**

```
addFeature(): void {
    let data = this.fb.group({
      group1: new FormControl("grp_1"),
      group2: this.fb.group({
        data: new FormControl("grp_2")
      }),
      group3: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          data: new FormControl("grp_3")
        })
      ])
    });
    this.features.push(data);
  }
```

[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-eg-q4njux)

Comment: Yeah , IN Form Array->Form Array->formControl we can bind in html  but not able to bind  Form Array(Features)->Form group(group2)->FormGroup(data) in HTML ie nested formgroup in formarray cannot bind in html Please do help??

Comment: Can you create example stackblitz?

Comment: Please follow this link --->                  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-eg-s1v5zs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-eg-kgijm5

Answer (score 1):

You have `formControlName="group2"` on your text `<input>`. Instead, you should bind the `data` control of the `group2` form group to the input: `formControlName="data"`.

Comment: This is a sample object "group2" ,In Real time :I have n number of object inside ("group2") to bind under this nested formgroup data ,name ,id etc... is there any way..?